# Excel users all have different colours

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a workbook shared by a number of users (it is in fact a dreaded shared-workbook). Depending on who saved it, the background colours seem to shift. What was green when I save it, may be a different shade of green when someone else saves it and may be blue when a third person saves it.

Do users have  individual colour profiles of some sort? If they do, how can I make sure that they get standardised?

Many thanks

M

Comment: Are different versions of Excel being used?

Comment: Different versions of excel have different color palettes, that is why you are experiencing this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have revision tracking turned on.  Read up on it here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/track-changes-in-a-shared-workbook-HP010342961.aspx

Each reviewer gets a color assignment, and the edits they've done show up highlighted in their color.